# ASP.NET 4.0 Menu Control - Why doesn't the rendered <div> element act like a normal block element and fill up its parent's width?

Tags: asp.net, css

The title poses the question. Here's a scenario:

You're making a website with ASP.NET 4.0/C#, although xml alone is suitable for this example. The site will have a site map and a default page with a menu control, as follows:

**Web.sitemap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Home"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="~/1.aspx" title="Link 1" description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/2.aspx" title="Link 2"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/3.aspx" title="Link 3"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/4.aspx" title="Link 4" description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/5.aspx" title="Link 5" description="" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      <pages theme="Default" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      </pages>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

**Default.aspx**
*Note: Only the contents of the `<form>` element are shown.*

```
<asp:Menu 
  ID="navMenu" 
  DataSourceID="srcSiteMap"
  StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
  RenderingMode="list"
  CssClass="navMenu"
  runat="server"> 
</asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="srcSiteMap" runat="server"
```

ShowStartingNode="false" />

**StyleSheet.css**
_Note: This file is included in `~/App_Themes/Default/` and referenced in

Web.config._

```
body {
width:800px;
margin:0px auto;
}
.navMenu {
background-color:Yellow;
}
```

With these files in use, the asp.net 4.0 engine will proceed to render a column of broken links. What I am unable to explain is why this column is only the width of the widest link, instead of the width of the 800px body element. Even if `width:auto;` is specified for the `.navMenu` css class, this remains the case. However, if you specify `width:100%;` or `width:800px;`, this fixes the problem, whatever the problem may be.

Now, I am hardly a master of css or the asp.net rendering engine, but looking at the page's source, I simply can't find any explanation. Perhaps I'm overlooking the obvious, but in the name of science, I hope to discover the truth! Should someone find the time to create a new visual studio solution, or simply know off the top of his/her head, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: what is the doc type of your page

Comment: have you tried display:block in .navMenu

Comment: display:block; has no effect in .navuMenu. Changing or removing the doctype does not appear to have an effect, but it's the default xhtml transitional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an issue within your .net creation program (e.g. Visual studio) or a browser? If it is not an issue in browser then it must be the program's own stylesheet

without seeing the html output this is a little tricky but I suspect you will have something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <ul class="navMenu">
      </ul>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

using firebug or something similar I would check to see what the highest item in the tier is with the small width. I suspect that the form element is somehow shrink wrapping (is it display:inline? floated?)

Comment: Almost on the money. The <ul> element for the Menu is contained in a div, as follows:

    <div class="navMenu">
      <ul ...></ul>
    </div>

I had never used Firebug before, but I downloaded it and started playing around. It appears some styles are being applied to particular elements. More specifically, it seems a javascript must be applying an element.style selector to all elements with the .navMenu ID, which includes varying properties, including float: left; That more or less answers my question, but as an addendum, do you know how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: override the same styles in your style sheet.  You will probably need to use the !important tag on your default values for them to override the embedded WebResource files for the NavMenu

Comment: Thanks. This will help me keep the styles in the .css file, and while it isn't the most elegant solution, it is certainly probably the easiest. I appreciate your time.